# How can I get the fileCreationDate to an accuracy of 6 decimal places when converted using timeIntervalSince1970?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nslog, nstimeinterval, nsdocumentdirectory

How can I get the `fileCreationDate` for a file stored in the `NSDocumentsDirectory` to an accuracy of 6 decimal places when converted to an `NSTimeInverval`?

Some code:

```
//Not accurate enough:
NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:myPhotoPath error:nil]; 
NSDate *creationDateOfPhoto = [fileAttribs fileCreationDate];
NSTimeInterval creationDateAsTimeInterval = [creationDateOfPhoto timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"Creation Date of Photo As Time Interval Since 1970: %f", creationDateAsTimeInterval);

//With the desired accuracy:
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval nowStampAsTimeInterval = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"Now As Time Interval Since 1970: %f", nowStampAsTimeInterval);
```

A sample output from this code is:

```
Creation Date of Photo As Time Interval Since 1970: 1373022866.000000
Now As Time Interval Since 1970:                    1373022884.294028
```

Is it possible or is it a limitation of storage in NSDocuments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a OS level limitation. [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus), the file system which is used by iOS, has a date resolution of one second - this is why all your file timestamps are whole seconds. Sub second precision isn't supported. Sorry!

Comment: Thank Ixt for the answer.  Never mind.  I got around it anyway but just wondered why.